# Securing data while calling API and store it in SQL

Tags: java, android, sql, security

In my android application user will enter his ID , then I will call an API to store this information in SQL database.

For the ID It's sensitive information and it need to be secured while calling the API and also the way it saved in the database.

I have 0 knowledge about security. I searched a lot and didn't understand which way is correct and better.

If you could help me with some ideas based on your experience and i will do a further researching on it and how to actually implement it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need 2 solutions:

1) secure api for your data

2)secure way for store them

for first issue, you can use https url and it will be secure for getting data at first and then you must use unique token that generate for each user or more you can use account manager in android for secure use data in API calls.

and for storing data, you can use Realm database that can encrypt data and save it in app, its key value database and you can use docs for more knowledge.

with this ways you can secure your data in your app.its a general securing way in android

if you need more help update me in comments

Comment: Thanks for your response ! but i don't want to save the data locally using realm , User will enter his id and I will call api to store this information to SQL server database.